# map field types in Servicestack.OrmLite

Tags: c#, oracle, servicestack, ormlite-servicestack

Lets say I have a field in the DB with possible values 'Y', 'N', NULL. I want to represent it in my DTO with a boolean property ('N', NULL -> false, 'Y' - > true). Can I somehow plug into OrmLite to make the conversion myself (both directions, ofc) during the query/update/insert?
Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

ORMLite uses simple POCOs so you can do something like this:

```
public class MyDto
{
    // Values: Y, N, and NULL
    public string SomeDbField { get; set; }

    [Ignore]
    public bool SomeDbFieldAccessor
    {
        get { return (SomeDbField != null && SomeDbField == "Y"); }
        set { SomeDbField = value ? "Y" : "N"; }
    }
}
```

The `[Ignore]` attribute on the accessor field will tell ORMLite that the field should not be saved to / read from the database.

Comment: That is exactly what I thought I would have to do if OrmLite didn't have this feature :). Thank you for confirming